# How to add index signature to export default object

Tags: typescript

first.ts:

```
import textFilters from './second'
Object.keys(textFilters).forEach(key => {
  Vue.filter(key, textFilters[key])
})
```

second.ts:

```
export default {
  trimDescription: (text: string, length: number): string => {
    return text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error about missing index signature. How can i actually add it to `export default {}`?

**UPDATE 1**

i can do it this way in second.ts:

```
interface Keys {
  [key: string]: any
}

const obj: Keys = {
  trimDescription: (text: string, length: number): string => {
    return text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text
  }
}

export default obj
```

But the initial question is, can i do this with `export default {}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually fixed this:

main.ts:

```
import textFilters, { Keys } from '@/filters/text'
(Object.keys(textFilters) as Array<(keyof Keys)>).forEach(key => {
  Vue.filter(key, textFilters[key])
})
```

text.ts:

```
export interface Keys {
  trimDescription(text: string, length: number): string
}

export default {
  trimDescription(text: string, length: number): string {
    return text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) + '...' : text
  }
}
```

The key was: `Object.keys(textFilters) as Array<(keyof Keys)>`

Answer (score 0):

Within the object, define the index signature like so:

```
{
   [index: string]: any;

    ...rest of your object
}
```

Replace any with the actual types you expect your object values to have.